# "/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `'."" when using grub customizer

Tags: grub2

I updated to Ubuntu 14.04.1 and now I can't get into Grub Customizer.
I am getting the following errors:

```
chroot '/media/grub-customizer_recovery_root_mountpoint' grub-mkconfig couldn't be executed successfully. error message:
 Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-67-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-67-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-7-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-7-generic
cat: /video.lst: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `'.
No path or device is specified.
Usage: grub-probe [OPTION...] [OPTION]... [PATH|DEVICE]
Try 'grub-probe --help' or 'grub-probe --usage' for more information.
```

Any ideas or help?

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with grub customizr, but i assume it will call the underlying scripts, namely grub-mkconfig which might fail here.

Run the debug command from here [Debian Bug 736928](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=736928)

```
sudo sh -x /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig >/dev/null 2>grub-mkconfig.err
```

and look at grub-mkconfig.err, which showed me what the problem was for me, a customized 00_header file which was not valid anymore.

You might also be facing a problem where GRUB is installed into /boot/grub/i386-pc but the GRUB_PREFIX variable isnt set anywhere, just like mentioned [here](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=32251).

Fix this by making a backup of /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig and add the following lines at the top, where the other variables are set

```
GRUB_PREFIX="/boot/grub/i386-pc"
export GRUB_PREFIX
```

You might just set the variable somewhere else, thats up to you.